# Ionic cli exiting after grunt serve

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue trying to run my ionic project. Upon exacting "grunt serve", it performs the various tasks specified in the Grunt file except it stops and exits the Ionic CLI immediately after it opens the ionic CLI. I will provide a snapshot of the terminal here:

[image]

Has anyone else ever had this issue? I would appreciate any and all help. Thank you so much for any response!

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure if it matters, however upon installation, the program was unable to install the cordova-whitelist plugin.

EDIT 2: Here is the Gruntfile.js

'

```
// Generated on 2015-05-22 using generator-ionic 0.7.3
    'use strict';

    var _ = require('lodash');
    var path = require('path');
    var cordovaCli = require('cordova');
    var spawn = process.platform === 'win32' ? require('win-spawn') :        require('child_process').spawn;

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: 'app',
      scripts: 'scripts',
      styles: 'styles',
      images: 'images',
      test: 'test',
      dist: 'www'
    },

    // Environment Variables for Angular App
    // This creates an Angular Module that can be injected via ENV
    // Add any desired constants to the ENV objects below.
    // https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-add-constants
    ngconstant: {
      options: {
        space: '  ',
        wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
        name: 'config',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/configuration.js'
      },
      development: {
        constants: {
          ENV: {
            name: 'development',
            apiEndpoint: 'http://dev.yoursite.com:10000/'
          }
        }
      },
      production: {
        constants: {
          ENV: {
            name: 'production',
            apiEndpoint: 'http://api.yoursite.com/'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep', 'newer:copy:app']
      },
      html: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:app']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:app', 'newer:jshint:all']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer', 'newer:copy:tmp']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
        tasks: ['ngconstant:development', 'newer:copy:app']
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      },
      coverage: {
        options: {
          port: 9002,
          open: true,
          base: ['coverage']
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/unit/**/*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.temp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.temp'
    },

    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.temp/<%= yeoman.styles %>/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.temp/<%= yeoman.styles %>/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
    },



    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        staging: '.temp',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>/**/*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        //root: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        noRebase: true
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'templates/**/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.images %>/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '*.html',
            'templates/**/*.html',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.temp/<%= yeoman.images %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.images %>',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>',
        dest: '.temp/<%= yeoman.styles %>/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      },
      fonts: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'app/bower_components/ionic/release/fonts/',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts/',
        src: '*'
      },
      vendor: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/vendor',
        dest: '.temp/<%= yeoman.styles %>/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      },
      app: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/',
        src: [
          '**/*',
          '!**/*.(scss,sass,css)',
        ]
      },
      tmp: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.temp',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/',
        src: '**/*'
      }
    },

    concurrent: {
      ionic: {
        tasks: [],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      server: [
        'copy:styles',
        'copy:vendor',
        'copy:fonts'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles',
        'copy:vendor',
        'copy:fonts'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'copy:vendor',
        'copy:fonts'
      ]
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>/main.css': [
    //         '.temp/<%= yeoman.styles %>/**/*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.styles %>/**/*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    // These will override any config options in karma.conf.js if you create it.
    karma: {
      options: {
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.test %>/mock/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.test %>/spec/**/*.js'
        ],
        autoWatch: false,
        reporters: ['dots', 'coverage'],
        port: 8080,
        singleRun: false,
        preprocessors: {
          // Update this if you change the yeoman config path
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js': ['coverage']
        },
        coverageReporter: {
          reporters: [
            { type: 'html', dir: 'coverage/' },
            { type: 'text-summary' }
          ]
        }
      },
      unit: {
        // Change this to 'Chrome', 'Firefox', etc. Note that you will need
        // to install a karma launcher plugin for browsers other than Chrome.
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        background: true
      },
      continuous: {
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
      }
    },

    // ngAnnotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.temp/concat/<%= yeoman.scripts %>',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.temp/concat/<%= yeoman.scripts %>'
        }]
      }
    }

  });

  // Register tasks for all Cordova commands
  _.functions(cordovaCli).forEach(function (name) {
    grunt.registerTask(name, function () {
      this.args.unshift(name.replace('cordova:', ''));
      // Handle URL's being split up by Grunt because of `:` characters
      if (_.contains(this.args, 'http') || _.contains(this.args, 'https')) {
        this.args = this.args.slice(0, -2).concat(_.last(this.args, 2).join(':'));
      }
      var done = this.async();
      var exec = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'cordova.cmd' : 'cordova';
      var cmd = path.resolve('./node_modules/cordova/bin', exec);
      var flags = process.argv.splice(3);
      var child = spawn(cmd, this.args.concat(flags));
      child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        grunt.log.writeln(data);
      });
      child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        grunt.log.error(data);
      });
      child.on('close', function (code) {
        code = code ? false : true;
        done(code);
      });
    });
  });

  // Since Apache Ripple serves assets directly out of their respective platform
  // directories, we watch all registered files and then copy all un-built assets
  // over to <%= yeoman.dist %>/. Last step is running cordova prepare so we can refresh the ripple
  // browser tab to see the changes. Technically ripple runs `cordova prepare` on browser
  // refreshes, but at this time you would need to re-run the emulator to see changes.
  grunt.registerTask('ripple', ['wiredep', 'newer:copy:app', 'ripple-emulator']);
  grunt.registerTask('ripple-emulator', function () {
    grunt.config.set('watch', {
      all: {
        files: _.flatten(_.pluck(grunt.config.get('watch'), 'files')),
        tasks: ['newer:copy:app', 'prepare']
      }
    });

    var cmd = path.resolve('./node_modules/ripple-emulator/bin', 'ripple');
    var child = spawn(cmd, ['emulate']);
    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      grunt.log.writeln(data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      grunt.log.error(data);
    });
    process.on('exit', function (code) {
      child.kill('SIGINT');
      process.exit(code);
    });

    return grunt.task.run(['watch']);
  });

  // Dynamically configure `karma` target of `watch` task so that
  // we don't have to run the karma test server as part of `grunt serve`
  grunt.registerTask('watch:karma', function () {
    var karma = {
      files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/<%= yeoman.scripts %>/**/*.js', '<%= yeoman.test %>/spec/**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma:unit:run']
    };
    grunt.config.set('watch', karma);
    return grunt.task.run(['watch']);
  });

  // Wrap ionic-cli commands
  grunt.registerTask('ionic', function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var script = path.resolve('./node_modules/ionic/bin/', 'ionic');
    var flags = process.argv.splice(3);
    var child = spawn(script, this.args.concat(flags), { stdio: 'inherit' });
    child.on('close', function (code) {
      code = code ? false : true;
      done(code);
    });
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'wiredep',
    'clean',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'karma:unit:start',
    'watch:karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'compress') {
      return grunt.task.run(['compress', 'ionic:serve']);
    }

    grunt.config('concurrent.ionic.tasks', ['ionic:serve', 'watch']);
    grunt.task.run(['wiredep', 'init', 'concurrent:ionic']);
  });
  grunt.registerTask('emulate', function() {
    grunt.config('concurrent.ionic.tasks', ['ionic:emulate:' + this.args.join(), 'watch']);
    return grunt.task.run(['init', 'concurrent:ionic']);
  });
  grunt.registerTask('run', function() {
    grunt.config('concurrent.ionic.tasks', ['ionic:run:' + this.args.join(), 'watch']);
    return grunt.task.run(['init', 'concurrent:ionic']);
  });
  grunt.registerTask('build', function() {
    return grunt.task.run(['init', 'ionic:build:' + this.args.join()]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('init', [
    'clean',
    'ngconstant:development',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'newer:copy:app',
    'newer:copy:tmp'
  ]);


  grunt.registerTask('compress', [
    'clean',
    'ngconstant:production',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('coverage', 
    ['karma:continuous',
    'connect:coverage:keepalive'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'wiredep',
    'newer:jshint',
    'karma:continuous',
    'compress'
  ]);
};
```

'

Comment: Post your Gruntfile.js. The cordova-whitelist plugin is used for Content Security Policy, for things like ajax requests to different domains, and loading content from CDNs. Won't cause you a problem at this stage.

Comment: i'm having the same problem. With grunt serve:compress it al works

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`grunt-concurrent@2.0.0` can not keep running `ionic:serve` and `watch` tasks in parallel. Details of the issue [sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/pull/52)

It's possible to solve the issue downgrading to `grunt-concurrent@1.0.0`, using the command:

**To fix the issue:**

`npm install grunt-concurrent@1.0.0 --save-dev`

Also is posible use `grunt-parallel` as alternative 
[grunt-parallel](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel) works fine to this case.

**Altenative fix the issue:**

1. Install `grunt-parallel`with `npm install grunt-parallel --save-dev`
2. Add configuration for parallel task

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  parallel: {
    assets: {
      options: {
        grunt: true
      },
      tasks: ['ionic:serve', 'watch']
    }
  }
});
```

3. Modify the serve task registration `grunt.registerTask('serve', ... )`

   - Remove `grunt.config('concurrent.ionic.tasks', ['ionic:serve', 'watch']);`
   - Modify `grunt.task.run` with `grunt.task.run(['wiredep', 'init', 'concurrent:ionic', 'parallel:assets']);`

finally, you will see the serve task registration, like this:

```js
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
  if (target === 'compress') {
        return grunt.task.run(['compress', 'ionic:serve']);
  }
           
  grunt.task.run(['wiredep', 'init', 'concurrent:ionic', 'parallel:assets']);
});
```

4. Run `grunt serve`

Comment: Thanks, grunt-concurrent 1.0.0 did the trick (have not tried fix 2)

Comment: youre getting way less credit than you deserve mate.. this was a life-saver!. @1.0.0 solved the issue.. havent tried fix #2 since #1 worked.. :) thanks!

Comment: You save me me. THanks

Comment: Using grunt-parallel is also working. But I can't see message in cmd when I modify file. why?